# template function of template class with function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, function-pointers

I found some nice property templates [here](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/255).

These allow me to make a string property for a name like this:

```
class Entity {
    const std::string& get_name() const;
    const std::string& set_name(const std::string& name);
public:
    UnrestrictedProperty<std::string, Entity, &Entity::get_name, &Entity::set_name> name;
    ...
}
```

Using this template:

```
template <class Type, class Object, const Type&(Object::*real_getter)() const, const Type&(Object::*real_setter)(const Type&)>
class UnrestrictedProperty { ... }
```

Now I'd like to overload the << operator, but I can't figure out how to make a template template when function pointers are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution can be do declare a non member function like this:

```
template <class Type, class Object, const Type&(Object::*real_getter)() const, const Type&(Object::*real_setter)(const Type&)>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const UnrestrictedProperty<Type, Object, real_getter, real_setter> unrestricted_property) {
    return (output << unrestricted_property.get());
}
```

Please note that here is no need of the keyword friend because we are using get() method which is a public member function.

Furthermore it is usually better to return complex object like `std::string` by const reference and to avoid a copy.
I wanted to add that a method that is not modifying the object must be const as well, I am talking about `get_name` here.

Comment: Thank, you. (I improved the question.)